# word-wrap:break-word does not seem to work

Tags: css

I used the below word-wrap in a div, but it does not seem to work at all.  Any alternatives.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

This is CSS 3, how about CSS 2
Thanks
Jean

Comment: In what browsers do you expect it to work?

Comment: Chrome it does work, I dont expect it to work on IE, but does not work on FF

Comment: It should work in IE (even IE6) and Firefox 3.5+ if I remember correctly. Can't find the page on quirksmode.org right now.

Comment: It isn't implemented in Firefox 3.6+, but will when css3 is released.

Comment: Referred Wrapping Long URLs and Text Content with CSS http://perishablepress.com/wrapping-content/

Comment: Also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889508/using-word-wrap-break-word-within-a-table

Answer (score 2):

This is a CSS3 attribute, so make sure that your/the visitors browser supports CSS3.

Comment: I am testing this in chrome and FF

Answer (score 1):

Try:

div {

```
text-align: justify;
white-space: normal !important;
```

}

and also set a fixed width on the div.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
div.mydiv 
{
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Above doesn't work.

FF does not support this CSS3 selector as documented here [Mozilla.org forum](https://developer.mozilla.org/web-tech/2008/08/20/word-wrap-break-word/). and [Mozilla bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=543211)

Try using overflows or use

```
text-align:justify;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox only supports word-wrap from 3.5 [(see doc)](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Word-wrap). You can use white-space [(doc)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space) for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
.mydiv1 {
word-break: break-word;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;}

.mydiv2 {
word-break: break-all;}
```

At class mydiv1 is a combination of 'word-break: break-all' and 'word-wrap: break-word'. While at class mydiv2 only 'word-break: break-all'.

[Sentrapedagang.com](http://www.sentrapedagang.com)