# Using "word-wrap: break-word" within a table

Tags: css, google-chrome, html-table, word-wrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Word-wrap in a html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-a-html-table)

This text behaves exactly the way I want on Google Chrome (and other modern browsers):

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; width:100%; word-wrap: break-word;">
  <p>
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
  </p>
</div>
```

1. When the browser is wide enough, a+ and b+ are on the same line.

   ```
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
   ```
2. As you narrow the browser, a+ and b+ are put on separate lines.

   ```
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
   ```
3. When b+ can no longer fit, it is broken and put on two lines (for a total of three lines).

   ```
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
   bbbbbbbb
   ```

That's all great.

In my situation, however, this is not a `div` but a `table`, like so:

```
<table style="border:1px solid black; width:100%; word-wrap:break-word;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In this case, #1 and #2 happen, but not #3. That is, the table stops narrowing after step 2 and step 3 doesn't ever happen. The break-word doesn't seem to be filtering down.

Does anyone know how make #3 happen?  The solution only need work in Chrome, but it it also worked in other browsers that would be even better.

P.S. "Don't use tables" is not helpful.

Comment: Fascinating problem, not seen it before. It seems though this topic a similar (the same?) question was asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-a-html-table

Comment: There's lots of discussion on related issues here and elsewhere. There is definitely a lot of confusion around this issue and a lot of browser incompatibilities.

Comment: Referred Wrapping Long URLs and Text Content with CSS http://perishablepress.com/wrapping-content/

Answer (score 146, accepted):

`table-layout: fixed` will get force the cells to fit the table (and not the other way around), e.g.:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black; width: 100%; word-wrap:break-word;
              table-layout: fixed;">
  <tr>
    <td>
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Note, with `table-layout: fixed` you loose the 'dynamic column width' feature of tables - all columns will be set to the same size.

Answer (score 26):

You can try this:

`td p {word-break:break-all;}`

This, however, makes it appear like this when there's enough space, unless you add a `<br>` tag:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

So, I would then suggest adding `<br>` tags where there are newlines, if possible.

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LLyH3/3/

Also, if this doesn't solve your problem, there's a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1258416/445210).