# CSS: In HTML table, word-wrap doesn't work with float: left

Tags: html, css

I have a three column table and I want to set a text background in the cell basing on the length of the content. But when I set float: left, word-wrap doesn't work well.

```
table {
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

This is the content in each cell.

```
.read{
    min-height: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 25% 0%, 25% 100%, from(rgba(142, 175, 196, 1.0)), to(rgba(118, 146, 164, 1.0)));
    float:left;
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="36px">..</td>
        <td>
            <div class="read">
            looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooog
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If I remove float:left;, the background won't match the length of the content but word-wrap does work.
How could I modify my CSS?

Comment: could you try adding display: inline-block; to your .read class?

Comment: share your markup please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889508/using-word-wrap-break-word-within-a-table

Comment: @Anpel display: inline-block works the the same as float:left in my css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**add** display:inline;

```
 .read{
        min-height: 20px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 25% 0%, 25% 100%, from(rgba(142, 175, 196, 1.0)), to(rgba(118, 146, 164, 1.0)));
        **display:inline;**
    }
```

Comment: yes, this makes the content wrap, but the background appears behind the content line by line instead of the whole block. I'm trying to solve this..thank you!

Comment: hmm I am interested in why this works. As far as I can remember, inline elements needs to have width set in order for it to word-wrap?