# How to let <td> only break-all when break-word fails?

Tags: html, css, html-table

As titled.

Possible similar to [Using "word-wrap: break-word" within a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889508/using-word-wrap-break-word-within-a-table) but the answers did not resolve my problem.

Example:

```
| --<td style="width:100px">(example)-- |
|                                       |
| Example 1:                            |
| something long something something something | <- this line should break into below:
|                                       |
| something long something something    |
| something                             | <- when break at word is possible
|                                       |
|                                       |
| Example 2:                            |
| somethinglongsomethingsomethingsomethingsomething | <- this line should break into below:
|                                       |
| somethinglongsomethingsomethingsometh |
| ingsomething                          | <- when break at word is not possible
```

It seems like I can either use `break-word` or `break-all`.

For `break-word`, example 1 works but example 2 stretches the table, regardless if I set `table-layout: fixed` in the table or not.

For `break-all`, example 2 works but example 1 also breaks the word.

Is there any clever way to let the table break the word only when it have to?

Comment: Basically...No! You'll have to pick on or the other.

Comment: If you use fixed width you don't need table-layout: fixed use only break-all

Comment: @Paulie_D Oh that's a sad news. So the conclusion is that the `div` supports that but `td` doesn't?

Comment: @GermanoPlebani Unless I use `break-all`, it widens the `td` even if all columns have fixed width. But if I use `break-all`, the table looks awful. Any workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct HTML-only or CSS-only way to do this.

You could go overkill and use a javascript solution, however. One strategy: estimate the maximum number of characters which would fit in one line of the table cel, search the string within the table cel for single words which are longer than that number, and insert a `<wbr>` tag in the word (or hyphenate it, or add a space, or etc) at that point.

```js
$('td').each(function() {
  var contents = $(this).html();
  contents = contents.replace(/(\w{25})/g,"$1<wbr>");
  $(this).html(contents);
  });
```

```css
td {border:1px solid; max-width: 15em;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>This has short words</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This has a long word: bababadalgharaghtakamminarronnkonnbronntonnerronntuonnthunntrovarrhounawnskawntoohoohoordenenthurnuk!</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Now I need to figure out how to do it when there are many `td`s with different width, and also the backward compatibility with non-HTML5 browsers! Thanks! BTW, never saw `<wbr>` before, learnt something absolutely new!

Comment: I suppose in theory you could spam a <wbr> tag in between every letter of long words, rather than try to estimate the "correct" number for each column, but I'm not sure if that would cause rendering issues with large amounts of content...