# Break word in <td> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to be able to show the entire text contained in the `<td>` element.
Here you can test it :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var users = [],
 shuffled = [],
 loadout = $("#loadout"),
 insert_times = 30,
 duration_time = 10000;
 $("#roll").click(function(){
  users = [];
  //var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
    var lines = "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident \n adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt".split('\n')
  if(lines.length < 2){
   $("#msgbox").slideToggle(100);
   setTimeout(function() {
      $("#msgbox").slideToggle(100);
   }, 3000);
   return false;
  }
  for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
   if(lines[i].length > 0){
    users.push(lines[i]);
   }
  }
  $("#roll").attr("disabled",true);
  var scrollsize = 0,
  diff = 0;
  $(loadout).html("");
  $("#log").html("");
  loadout.css("left","100%");
  if(users.length < 10){
   insert_times = 20;
   duration_time = 5000;
  }else{
   insert_times = 10;
   duration_time = 10000;
  }
  for(var times = 0; times < insert_times;times++){
   shuffled = users;
   shuffled.shuffle();
   for(var i = 0;i < users.length;i++){
    loadout.append('<td><div class="roller"><div>'+shuffled[i]+'</div></div></td>');
    scrollsize = scrollsize + 192;
   }
  }
  
  
  diff = Math.round(scrollsize /2);
  diff = randomEx(diff - 300,diff + 300);
  $( "#loadout" ).animate({
   left: "-="+diff
  },  duration_time, function() {
   $("#roll").attr("disabled",false);
   $('#loadout').children('td').each(function () {
    var center = window.innerWidth / 2;
    if($(this).offset().left < center && $(this).offset().left + 185 > center){
     var text = $(this).children().text();
     $("#log").append("THE WINNER IS<br/> <span class=\"badge\">"+text+"</span>");
     
    }
    
   });
  });
 });
 Array.prototype.shuffle = function(){
  var counter = this.length, temp, index;
  while (counter > 0) {
   index = (Math.random() * counter--) | 0;
   temp = this[counter];
   this[counter] = this[index];
   this[index] = temp;
  }
 }
 function randomEx(min,max)
 {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
 }
});
```

```css
.topbox{
    
 background:white;
 padding-bottom:40px;
    /*
 background: #0f161d;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #0f161d 0%, #131b24 51%, #0f161d 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#0f161d), color-stop(51%,#131b24), color-stop(100%,#0f161d));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #0f161d 0%,#131b24 51%,#0f161d 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #0f161d 0%,#131b24 51%,#0f161d 100%); 
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #0f161d 0%,#131b24 51%,#0f161d 100%); 
 background: linear-gradient(to right,  #0f161d 0%,#131b24 51%,#0f161d 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0f161d', endColorstr='#0f161d',GradientType=1 );
 box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 black;
    */
}

.rollbox{
    width:100%;
 height:200px;
 background:white;
 border:1px solid #eb3b5a;
    border-radius: 5px;
 overflow-x:auto;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
 padding:0;
}
.rollbox > table{
    background-color: yellow;
 width:auto;
 height:200px;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 
}
#loadout{
 position:absolute;
 top:10px;
 left:5px;
 z-index:1;
 background:#121619;
}

.roller {
    border-right:1px solid white;
 position:relative;
 display: block;
 height:100%;
 text-align:center;
    color:white;
 line-height:180px;
 font-size:0.8em;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family:sans-serif;
}
.roller div{
 display:block;
 height:50px;
 line-height:50px;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;
 left:0;
 
}

.badge{
 padding-top:5px;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 1px black;
 margin-bottom:20px;
}
.line{
 width:2px;
 height:198px;
 top:1px;
 left:50%;
 position:absolute;
 background:#eb3b5a;
 opacity:0.6;
 z-index:2;
 
}

.roller{
 height:180px;
 
 width:180px;
 margin-right:10px;
 /*box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 black;*/
 background:url(http://re3ker.de/raffle/images/purple.jpg);
}
tr,table,td{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

td:nth-child(even) .roller{
 background:url(http://re3ker.de/raffle/images/blue.jpg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
      </button>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row topbox">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-3 rollbox">
               <div class="line"></div>
               <table>
                  <tbody>
                     <tr id="loadout" style="left: -11248px;">
                        <td>
                           <div class="roller">
                              <img width="110" src="">
                              <div style="background-color:red;">
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </td>

                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
               <div id="msgbox" class="alert alert-warning" style="margin-top:20px;display:none;">You need to add at least 2 lines!</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

</div>
<button id="roll" class="btn btn-success form-control">Roll</button>
```

The text contained is

```
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident
```

And

```
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
```

I tried using `<p style="word-break: break-word;"></p>` but this doesn't break

Here are where the black box are generated :

```
loadout.append('<td><div class="roller"><div>'+shuffled[i]+'</div></div></td>');
```

Comment: You can take a look to an older answer: [Using “word-wrap: break-word” within a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889508/using-word-wrap-break-word-within-a-table)

Comment: Your `line-height` matches your `height` is your main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just update your code with few CSS updates. Change `line-height:50px` to `line-height:normal` and add `word-break: break-word` in `.roller div` css. Try this I hope i'll resolve your issue. Thanks

```
.roller div{
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    line-height:normal;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var users = [],
 shuffled = [],
 loadout = $("#loadout"),
 insert_times = 30,
 duration_time = 10000;
 $("#roll").click(function(){
  users = [];
  //var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
    var lines = "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident \n adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt".split('\n')
  if(lines.length < 2){
   $("#msgbox").slideToggle(100);
   setTimeout(function() {
      $("#msgbox").slideToggle(100);
   }, 3000);
   return false;
  }
  for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
   if(lines[i].length > 0){
    users.push(lines[i]);
   }
  }
  $("#roll").attr("disabled",true);
  var scrollsize = 0,
  diff = 0;
  $(loadout).html("");
  $("#log").html("");
  loadout.css("left","100%");
  if(users.length < 10){
   insert_times = 20;
   duration_time = 5000;
  }else{
   insert_times = 10;
   duration_time = 10000;
  }
  for(var times = 0; times < insert_times;times++){
   shuffled = users;
   shuffled.shuffle();
   for(var i = 0;i < users.length;i++){
    loadout.append('<td><div class="roller"><div>'+shuffled[i]+'</div></div></td>');
    scrollsize = scrollsize + 192;
   }
  }
  
  
  diff = Math.round(scrollsize /2);
  diff = randomEx(diff - 300,diff + 300);
  $( "#loadout" ).animate({
   left: "-="+diff
  },  duration_time, function() {
   $("#roll").attr("disabled",false);
   $('#loadout').children('td').each(function () {
    var center = window.innerWidth / 2;
    if($(this).offset().left < center && $(this).offset().left + 185 > center){
     var text = $(this).children().text();
     $("#log").append("THE WINNER IS<br/> <span class=\"badge\">"+text+"</span>");
     
    }
    
   });
  });
 });
 Array.prototype.shuffle = function(){
  var counter = this.length, temp, index;
  while (counter > 0) {
   index = (Math.random() * counter--) | 0;
   temp = this[counter];
   this[counter] = this[index];
   this[index] = temp;
  }
 }
 function randomEx(min,max)
 {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
 }
});
```

```css
.topbox{
    
 background:white;
 padding-bottom:40px;
    /*
 background: #0f161d;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #0f161d 0%, #131b24 51%, #0f161d 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#0f161d), color-stop(51%,#131b24), color-stop(100%,#0f161d));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #0f161d 0%,#131b24 51%,#0f161d 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #0f161d 0%,#131b24 51%,#0f161d 100%); 
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #0f161d 0%,#131b24 51%,#0f161d 100%); 
 background: linear-gradient(to right,  #0f161d 0%,#131b24 51%,#0f161d 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0f161d', endColorstr='#0f161d',GradientType=1 );
 box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 black;
    */
}

.rollbox{
    width:100%;
 height:200px;
 background:white;
 border:1px solid #eb3b5a;
    border-radius: 5px;
 overflow-x:auto;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
 padding:0;
}
.rollbox > table{
    background-color: yellow;
 width:auto;
 height:200px;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 
}
#loadout{
 position:absolute;
 top:10px;
 left:5px;
 z-index:1;
 background:#121619;
}

.roller {
    border-right:1px solid white;
 position:relative;
 display: block;
 height:100%;
 text-align:center;
    color:white;
 line-height:180px;
 font-size:0.8em;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family:sans-serif;
}
.roller div{
 display:block;
 height:50px;
 line-height:normal;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;
 left:0;
 word-break: break-word;
}

.badge{
 padding-top:5px;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 1px black;
 margin-bottom:20px;
}
.line{
 width:2px;
 height:198px;
 top:1px;
 left:50%;
 position:absolute;
 background:#eb3b5a;
 opacity:0.6;
 z-index:2;
 
}

.roller{
 height:180px;
 
 width:180px;
 margin-right:10px;
 /*box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 black;*/
 background:url(http://re3ker.de/raffle/images/purple.jpg);
}
tr,table,td{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

td:nth-child(even) .roller{
 background:url(http://re3ker.de/raffle/images/blue.jpg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
      </button>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row topbox">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-3 rollbox">
               <div class="line"></div>
               <table>
                  <tbody>
                     <tr id="loadout" style="left: -11248px;">
                        <td>
                           <div class="roller">
                              <img width="110" src="">
                              <div style="background-color:red;">
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </td>

                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
               <div id="msgbox" class="alert alert-warning" style="margin-top:20px;display:none;">You need to add at least 2 lines!</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

</div>
<button id="roll" class="btn btn-success form-control">Roll</button>
```